# Visa to attend conference for paper presentation in USA

Tags: conference, visa

I am a master's degree student and I just got a paper approved for presentation at a conference that will last for a couple of days in the USA. Looking at the US Embassy website I didn't find it clear which visa I should apply for.

At first look, F1, F2, M1 or M2 looks most promising but they don't look like they apply for this exact purpose because they look appropriate for longer periods.

So, which visa should I apply for in that case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [B-1](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/temporary-visitors-for-business/b-1-temporary-business-visitor) visa is the correct one, IF you need a visa in the first place. As stated at the US Citizenship and Immigration Services page there, it covers (amongst other things):

> Traveling for a scientific, educational, professional or business convention, or a conference on specific dates

If you are eligible for an [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/) as a citizen of a visa waiver country, that is the easier route.